# admin uploads pre_get_posts not working as expected

Tags: php, wp-admin, pre-get-posts

It's 4pm and my brain stopped working an hour ago, and for the life of me I just can't work out why this isn't going as expected.

I am trying to show only the user's uploaded media in the Media Library. My filter works and returns only user's uploaded media until I add an if statement to make sure it only affects the Media Library.

```
/**
 * Hide others media from Contributors
 */
function ggstyle_hide_media_by_other($query)
{
    // When I add this if statement the filter no longer works.
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen->id != 'upload') {
        return $query;
    }

    if (current_user_can('contributor')) {
        $query->set('author', get_current_user_id());
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'ggstyle_hide_media_by_other');

// Debuggin function
function ggstyle_debug()
{
    // Debug shows that this screen IS 'upload'....
    echo "<pre>".print_r(get_current_screen(), true)."</pre>";
}
add_filter('admin_head', 'ggstyle_debug');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first off [`get_current_screen`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) only works in admin area but even in admin can cause problems on some page. Use the `$pagenow` global variable instead.

So now if you want to hide media **not** uploaded by a contributor this is how I would do it.

```
// Prevents user to see all uploads, only theirs
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse_users_own_attachments');
function wpse_users_own_attachments( $wp_query_obj ) {

  global $current_user, $pagenow;

  if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') )
    return;

  if( !in_array( $pagenow, array( 'upload.php', 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) )
    return;

  if( current_user_can('contributor') )
    $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->ID );

  return;
}
```